# Uri Builder not adding the port number in Android

Tags: java, android, url, uri

Whenever I try to add the port number to my URI.Builder in JAVA, the result excludes the Port number.

```
Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse("xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:11226").buildUpon();
builder.appendPath("login");
```

And the result is `xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:/login` which obviously results in `MalformedUrlException`.

How can I include the PORT in my URI using Uri.Builder?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you forget to add SCHEME in that xx part of your string. Parser may not handle ports without knowing the scheme.

*Java*

```java
Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse("https://127.0.0.1:11226").buildUpon();
builder.appendPath("login");
```

*Kotlin*

```kotlin
val builder = Uri.parse("https://192.168.0.2:11226").buildUpon()
builder.appendPath("reports")
builder.appendQueryParameter("sort", "desc")

println(builder) // output: https://192.168.0.2:11226/reports?sort=desc
```

Hope, it helps.